# Как правильно наследовать от базового класса и от интерфейса?

Tags: c#

У меня есть интерфейс

```
public interface iStrategy { }
```

от него создан базовый класс имеющий некий базовый функционал

```
public class Strategy : iStrategy { }
```

от этого базового класса наследуются

```
public class Strategy1 : Strategy { }

public class Strategy2 : Strategy { }
```

в другом классе есть функция которая задают текущую стратегию

```
// задать стратегию
void SetStrategy(iStrategy strategy)
{
    _strategy = strategy;
}
```

но при вызове

```
SetStrategy(new Strategy1());
```

выдаёт ошибку не удается преобразовать из Strategy1 в iStrategy

правильно ли будет записать вот так:

```
public class Strategy1 : Strategy, iStrategy { }

public class Strategy2 : Strategy, iStrategy { }
```

ТО есть сделать наследование от базового класса и от интерфейса. Вроде как базовый класс итак от интерфейса унаследован.
Можно записать так конечно:

```
SetStrategy((iStrategy)new Strategy1());
```

Как сделать грамотно?

Comment: Должно работать, как вы написали в первый раз, перепроверьте еще раз свой код

Comment: Ошибок нет: https://i.imgur.com/osfjxMy.png

Comment: тут момент такой что в базовом классе public class Strategy : iStrategy { } я хочу добавить общие функции, которые будут вызываться из Strategy1  и Strategy2, а иначе придётся одну и туже функцию определять в каждом классе

Comment: @Igor X, в таком случае вы должны сначала определить сигнатуры этих методов в интерфейсе

Comment: @Андрей Мне кажется, ТС говорит о `protected` методах базового класса, которые не являются частью интерфейса.

Comment: @Igor, у меня стеклянного шара нет )

Comment: @Андрей у меня, если Вы заметили, - есть :)

Comment: @Igor, вы считаете, автор реализует что-то вроде шаблонного метода? Тогда почему классы и интерфейсы называться стратегия?

Comment: стратегия это просто для примера. в итоге я вышел из ситуации за счёт множественного наследования. сделал наследование  Strategy1 и Strategy2 от интерфейса и от класса Strategy , который не стал наследовать от интерфейса.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш интерфейс

```
public interface iStrategy { }
```

определен больше чем в одном месте, и в вызове

```
SetStrategy(new Strategy1());
```

`iStrategy` из одного места (видимого классу `Strategy`) не может быть приведен к типу `iStrategy` из другого (видимого методу `SetStrategy`).

Comment: Что это? Битва экстрасенсов?

Answer (score 0):

Просто сделайте Strategy базовым и абстрактным классом, и уберите интерфейс.

```cs
public abstract class Strategy { // All members is example
 public int ExampleProperty { get; protected set; }
 public virtual bool ActByIt() { ExampleProperty += 1; 
  return ExampleProperty < 100000; }
 public Strategy() { ExampleProperty = 1; }
}

public class Strategy1 : Strategy {
 public Strategy1() : base() {}
 public override bool ActByIt() => return true;
}

public class Strategy2 : Strategy {
 public Strategy2() : base() {}
}

void Main() {
 Strategy currentStrategy;
 void SetStrategy(Strategy newS, out Strategy dest) => dest = newS;
 Strategy1 s1 = new Strategy1();
 Strategy2 s2 = new Strategy2();
 SetStrategy(s1, out currentStrategy);
 SetStrategy(s2, out currentStrategy);
}
```