# Один script ломает последующие в main.js

Tags: javascript

Ставлю этот код вначале main.js - все скрипты после него перестают работать. А если в конце кода - все скрипты работают. Из-за чего это? Переменные не перекликаются. Данный скрипт рабочий.

```
var newsbtn = document.querySelector('.news__to-all');
newsbtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    newsbtn.classList.toggle('news__to-all--show');
});
```

**Уточнение**. Этот скрипт ломает только скрипты **других** html-страниц. Скрипты общей с ним html-страницы работают.
На другой html-странице есть такой же скрипт, который так же ламает скрипты всех остальных html-страниц, кроме своей:

```
var portfBtn = document.querySelector('.portfolio__to-all');
portfBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    portfBtn.classList.toggle('portfolio__to-all--show');
});
```

В отдельных файлах все скрипты рабочие.

Comment: Такое может быть если в этом коде вылетает ошибка. Скорее всего элемент `newsbtn` не найдён и вы пытаетесь повесить событие на null

Comment: то есть, newsbtn нету в разметке? Но news__to-all как бы есть в разметке...

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, в разметке до данного скрипта отсутствуют элементы с классом `news__to-all`, из-за чего `querySelector` возвращает `null` и на `addEventListener` всё падает.

Comment: во-о-от, правильно. И никакой "битвы экстрасенсов" -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720904/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0/720915#720915

Comment: на другой html-странице, естественно отсутствуют. Или мне нужно для каждой страницы свою конкатинацию скриптов делать?